# Не получается развернуть gulp- Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

Уже несколько часов пытаюсь решить проблему с гальпом- не запускается. Реинстол не помог, пытался создавать нужные файлы, потому что до этого была другая ошибка, вроде помогло но сейчас вылезла эта и не могу ничего с ней сделать. Заранее спасибо!
Более подробно- хочу установить gulp, чтобы начать верстку используя HTML5 и SASS, как в видео, через GitBASH (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ccA_Jo6u-o&list=PLoq3Accf02PWYMRAU8RDRjSfJK52vUTo2), однако не получается запустить.

```
$ gulp -v
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 3.9.1
```

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:\litshop\node_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\index.js from D:\litshop\gulpfile.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in D:\litshop\gulpfile.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\litshop\gulpfile.js:6:22) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
```

Update: Я знаю, что такие проблемы уже решали, но те способы мне не помогли, либо я совсем не так делал :(

Comment: Мое почтение тому, кто прожал - и ничего не написал

Comment: Минус поставил я. Извините, я вообще чаще ставлю минусы, чем плюсы. Мне показалось, что вы недостаточно подробно объяснили, что пытаетесь сделать и где работаете. Убрал минус, в надежде, что более подробно разъясните ситуацию.